# JOptionPane showMessageDialog usage

Tags: java, joptionpane, messagebox

i'm beginner for java.
I have a project for final mark. I did something but i need your help.
My project is about mathematical operations. I should use `JOptionPane`.
I could first part `InputDialog` But I can't show them in the messagebox ( i used `println` only to see how to work). And of course the division part is very important. If you try to divide by zero it should be error and should write something about error. I'm waiting your help. Thanks a lot and best regards.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaMath3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1, num2, add, sub, multi;
        double div;



       num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write 1st number."));
       num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write 2nd number."));


        add = num1+num2;
            System.out.println("Addition " + add);

        sub = num1-num2;
            System.out.println("Subtraction " + sub);

        multi = num1*num2;
            System.out.println("Multiplication " + multi);

        if(num2 != 0 ) {
            div = (double) num1/num2;
            System.out.println("Division: " + div);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("A number can not divided by zero.");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a very simple you can  use the *JOPtionPane* method *showMessageDialog*

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "your message");
```

and here's a sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write 1st number."));
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write 2nd number."));
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sum = " + sum);
}
```

**After update**

here's a complete example

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num1, num2, add, sub, multi;
    double div;

    num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write 1st number."));
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write 2nd number."));

    add = num1 + num2;

    sub = num1 - num2;

    multi = num1 * num2;

    String result = "sum = " + add + "\n" + "sub = " + sub + "\nmul = " + multi;
    if (num2 != 0)
    {
        div = (double) num1 / num2;
        result = result + " \n div = " + div;
    } else
    {
        result = result + " \n div = A number can not divided by zero";
        System.out.println("A number can not divided by zero.");
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to show them in a box. And I dont know how to do division part. I used if else there. now what im gonna do?

Comment: you can use String concatenation, i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what mean by box but if you want them all in a same dialog box you could just write this line after your `else` statement:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Addition: " + add+ "\nSubtraction: " + sub+"\nMultiplication " + multi+ "\nDivision: " + div);
```